# Request atomicity within microservices bounded context

Tags: java, rest, architecture, microservices, spring-session

Our project consists of multiple microservices. These microservices form a boundary to which the entry point is not strictly defined meaning each of microservices can be requested and can request other services.

The situation we need to handle in this bounded microservice context is following:
client (other application) makes the request to perform some logic and change the data (PATCH),
request times out,
while request is being processed client fires the same request to repeat the operation,
operation successfully completes,
second request is being processed the same way and completes within it's time and client gets response.

Now what happened is that the same was processed two times because of first timeout.

We need to make sure the same request won't get processed and application will respond with former response and status code.

The subsequent request is identified by the same uuid.

Now, I understand it's the client that should do requesting more precisely or we should have a single request entry point in out micorservices bounded context, but in enterprise projects the team doesn't own the whole system therefore we are a bit constrained with the solutions we propose for the problem. with this in mind while trying to not reinvent the wheel this comes to my mind:

The microservices should utilize some kind of session sharing (spring-session?) with the ability to look up the request by it's `id` before it gets processed and in described case, when first is being processed and second arrives, wait for the completion of the 1st and respond to the second with data of the first that has timed out for a client.

What I am struggling with is imagining handling the asynchronicity of replying to the second one and how to listen for session state of the first request.

If spring-session would be used (for example with hazelcast) I'm lacking some kind of concrete session state handler which would get fired when request ends. Is there something like this to listen for?

No code written yet. It's an architectural thought experiment that I want to discuss.

If unsure of understanding, read second time please, then I'm happy to expand.

EDIT: first idea:

[image]
process would be as follows (with numbering on the image):

- (1) first request fired
- (3) processing started; (2) request timed out meanwhile;
- (4) client repeats the same request; program knows it has received the same request before because it knows the req. id.
- program checks the cache and the state of that request id 'pending' so it WAITS (async).
- computed result of first request is saved into the cache - orange square
- (5) program responds to the first request with the data that was meant to be for the first one

idea is that result checking and responding to the repeated request would be done in the filter chain so it won't actually hit the controller when the second request is asynchronously waiting for the operation triggered by the first request to be done (I see hazelcast has some events when rows are added/updated/evicted from the cache - dunno if it's working yet) and when complete just respond (somehow write to the HttpServletResponse). result would be saved into the cache in postHandling filter.

Thanks for insights.

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider this more of a caching paradigm.  Stick your request/responses into an external cache provider (REDIS or similar), indexed by uuid.  Having a TTL will allow your responses to automatically get cleaned up for requests that are never coming back, and the high-speed implementation (o1) should allow this to scale nicely.   It will also out-of-the-box give you an asynchronous model (not a stated goal, but always a nice option).

Comment: yes, basically it's kind of caching, but I need to be able to react on these duplicit requests properly, if possible recognize operation is in progress and wait till it ends then respond

Comment: Right, so put the request in cache by uuid (or some meaningful hash), when the response comes back, attach the response to it, and then respond to the client. 

The client checks each time to see if a request matching it's hash is already present, if it finds one, it uses the attached response, if no attached response, wait some reasonable timeout, and keep checking.  Eventually the thread with the initial client request will populate response, or the timeout will occur, and a new client request will come in to fulfill.

Comment: well, I'm not sure whether we are on the same page so I expanded the question with some operation proposal that I'm thinking about. anyway, I can not tell requestor to do something/change it's requesting process in any way..so it's up to our microservices context to respond well and do as little damage as possible :)